# Send MVC Text Input to Command Line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have an MVC application(C#) which executes a console application(C#) I have designed; the console application talks to a 3rd party WebAPI to retrieve data etc, in order to connect to the API i have embedded the credentials in the console application, I am looking to change this from instead of embedding the credentials in the console application, to being able to enter the credentials into the MVC web page and passing those into the console app (the app requests the username and password but as an alternative i embedded the credentials as an alternative requirement).

I am not entirely sure how to do this and looking for some pointers, if not a piece of code i can manipulate to do this.

Comment: You can maintain a database with username and credential. After the user logs in you can check for authorization and pass this credentials to your API

Comment: Thanks, that was the thought running through my head but I was told not to do it that way for some reason...

Comment: Ok so what was told not to do? using DataBase?

Comment: Not to store the credentials in a database and then have them automatically deleted once the application has finished it's job. Do you believe this is the only way or is there an alternative?

Comment: Start up a sample MVC application and by default you will be provided with a log-in page. Debug the code and find the method where the credential is accepted and call your method passing those credentials.

Comment: You could provide the credentials in the console app command line

Comment: I was told that was the way to do it but im unsure as how to pass the credentials via the command line arguments, any idea?